# MSBuild stuck on packages restore and sometimes throws exception

Tags: exception, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

It stuck at `Determining projects to restore...`

Stack trace of the exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: enumType
   at System.Enum.ToObject(Type enumType, Int32 value)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BinaryTranslator.BinaryReadTranslator.TranslateEnum[T](T& value, Int32 numericValue)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BinaryTranslator.BinaryReadTranslator.Translate(DateTime& value)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.LogMessagePacketBase.ReadEvaluationEvent(ITranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.LogMessagePacketBase.ReadProjectEvaluationStartedEventFromStream(ITranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.LogMessagePacketBase.ReadEventFromStream(LoggingEventType eventType, ITranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.LogMessagePacketBase.ReadFromStream(ITranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.LogMessagePacket.FactoryForDeserialization(ITranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketFactory.PacketFactoryRecord.DeserializeAndRoutePacket(Int32 nodeId, ITranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketFactory.DeserializeAndRoutePacket(Int32 nodeId, NodePacketType packetType, ITranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.NodeContext.ReadAndRoutePacket(NodePacketType packetType, Byte[] packetData, Int32 packetLength)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.NodeContext.BodyReadComplete(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.AsyncPSCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

It is Visual Studio 2022, exception happens not each time. Also it can successfully continue building if command executed once again. What can it be and what can I check?

**UPDATE**

Probably I need to tell that it is virtual guest (host is VMWare Workstation). If VM is running on PC with i6700 it works fine. In case of 5950x it fails. It looks like PC is too fast for MSBuild or it is some other hardware related issue. VM is identical absolutely (I copied it from PC with AMD CPU). Can it be bug of VS and some sort of race condition?

I have added `/maxcpucount:1` to temporarily workaround the issue. In original settings it was 8 (as cores in VM).

I have tested also `/maxcpucount:2` it works fine as well.

Comment: As you said, the exception doesn't happen every time and it can build successfully.

You can try this method:

 1. Clear NuGet cache. 
 2. Clear Visual Studio cache.
 3. Repair Visual Studio in Visual Studio Installer.
 4. Update Visual Studio to the latest Version.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT I have some additional information. I will update post.

Comment: The description of maxcpucount is "If you don't include this switch, the default value is 1. If you include this switch without specifying a value, MSBuild will use up to the number of processors in the computer." 
It looks like a hardware problem, have you tried to reconfigure the virtual machine? Maybe you can get support from VMWare.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT I have installed VS 2022 on host system to make some experiments, and got the same error during compilation on host system (cores = 8), MSBuild version 17.3.1+2badb37d1 for .NET Framework. So now we can be sure it is not VMWare.